# AWS EC2: "Invalid command: terminate"

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, flask

I have an EC-2 instance with an Amazon-Linux OS using Elastic Beanstalk to run a Flask application on AWS, and I am trying to use the `eb terminate` command to terminate my Elastic Beanstalk application. Here is the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html) on the method I'm trying to use:

[image]

However, when I run the command, I get the following response:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-14-25 python2.7]$ eb terminate ecco-app-dev
Invalid command: terminate
```

I am running eb version 2.6.4:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-14-25 python2.7]$ eb --version
AWS Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Interface v2.6.4
```

Does anyone know why I am getting an "Invalid command" response, or what I can do to terminate the eb application? I would be grateful for any help others can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eb terminate` is an eb version **3** command.

eb 2.6 only supports the following:

> ```
> branch
> delete
> events
> init
> logs
> push
> start
> status
> stop
> update
> ```

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cmd-commands.html

eb version 3 commands:

> ```
> abort
> clone
> config
> console
> create
> deploy
> events
> health
> init
> list
> local
> logs
> open
> platform
> printenv
> scale
> setenv
> ssh
> status
> swap
> terminate
> upgrade
> use
> ```

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-cmd-commands.html

Comment: Thanks jlyoung! This is helpful, but I needed to poke a bit more to figure out how to terminate my environments. I'll accept this and add my own solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

To terminate my eb environments, I visited:

https://console.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/?region=us-west-2

Where the value supplied to `region=` is the region that contains the environment to be shut down. On that page, one can easily deactivate multiple environments swiftly:

[image]